# Finite generation of a subset of an algebraic structure.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $\mathbb{N}^n$ of $n$ tuples of positive integers, with the following partially defined "operations" $\oplus_i$.

This operation takes in two vectors $A=(a_1,..a_i,...a_n)$, $B=(b_1,..b_i,...b_n)$, such that $a_j=b_j$ for $j\neq i$ and outputs $A\oplus_i B:=(a_1,...,a_i+b_i,...a_n)=(b_1,...,a_i+b_i,...b_n)$.

The question is then, given a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}^n$, such that $S$ is closed under $\oplus_i$ for all $i$, can we find finitely many elements $A_1,...A_m\in S$ such that $S$ is generated by these elements under the operations $\oplus_i$?

This is not a (totally) arbitrary question to consider, it arises from writing the operation of concatenating (multidimensional) rectangles in a (multidimensional) grid, and asking whether any such set is generated by a finite number of rectangles.

I'm not quite sure how to tag this question, so please add/remove tags if these aren't suitable.

Comment: There is no output because there is no computer program.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I'd say no. Take $S = \{ (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), ... \}$. It's easy to see you need $(p, p)$ be in generator $S$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: I think this is true but I can't seem to write down an easy proof. For the example given by @prosinac the set $S$ generated by $(2,2), (3,3), (4,4), \dots$ is generated by $(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(7,7)$. For this example, one can generate all pairs $(i,j)$ where $i, j \ge 20$.

Comment: True, I was wrong. In fact, $S$ i proposed isn't even closed with respect to described operation. And yes, I went to fast with example, of course you can generate larger $(p, p)$ from smaller ones. I didn't prove your exact claim with $i, j \geq 20$, but it doesn't even matter. And now thinking about it I'd also vote for true. In 1D it's easy known fact that from any finite number of elements of generator, if $gcd$ of all of them is $1$, you will be able to generate all numbers greater than some $N$.

Comment: I was thinking, by 1D intuition, that in 2D case, if $gcd$ of all first components $=1$, and same holds for second components, that you can generate every pair larger than $(N, N)$ for some $N$. However, naive test shows me that this might not be possible. I started with $\{(2,2), (3,3)\}$ and then adding random elements of the set thus increasing its size (but keeping elements below $(40, 40)$) and it doesn't seem all "big" pairs can be generated. Of course, this is no proof, but strong indication that the statement I wanted to prove is false. While the original statement might still be true.